# Размеры .ico значка

Tags: c#, wpf

Не могу понять, какими свойствами должен обладать значок ico в проекте WPF (размеры, еще что-то?), чтобы он выглядел адекватно в панели задач, в проводнике и других разделах Windows. Значок создаю из png картинки 150х150px средствами paint.net и соответствующего плагина. При создании он выглядит хорошо, но после добавления в проект Visual Studio, с ним случаются мало понятные мне метаморфозы (ребристость, зернистость, размытость и т.д.).

Comment: Попробуйте в иконку положить по крайней мере размеры 48х48, 32x32 и 16x16. Большая иконка будет автоскалироваться до маленькой, если маленького размера не будет. И качество будет понятно какое.

Comment: @VladD В иконке присутствуют все размеры от 16х16 до 128х128. Картинку png делаю в photoshop, дальше её конвертирую в ico. Возможно, я делаю что-то принципиально не так?

Comment: Да нет, вроде бы всё то. А как вы прикрепляете иконку к приложению? Может, покажете скриншот с проблемой?

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться конвертером http://icoconvert.com/image_to_icon_converter/ который позволяет в один файл склеить все нужные размеры

**UPD:** как применить в проекте можно прочитать тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952080/how-do-you-select-the-right-size-icon-from-a-multi-resolution-ico-file-in-wpf

Comment: Попробовал, там те же возможности, что и у paint.net - на результат не повлияло.

Comment: @Pavel дополнил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Нужны размеры: 16, 32, 48, 64, 128, 256.

Вот [это приложение](https://icons8.com/app) делает хорошие ico файлы 
из встроенных 52000 иконок. Можно сделать иконку из своего файла - но тогда нужен формат SVG.

Бонусом есть также конвертация векторных изображений в XAML - что может быть очень полезно при работе с WPF.

Вот видео https://vk.com/ru_icons8?z=video-128808289_456239017 для быстрого экскурса.